# how to get Disk Space used/free/total in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, space, disk

Seems that there is no standard functions to get used/free/total of Disk space in Common Lisp.

There is statvfs.h in Linux/Mac and GetDiskFreeSpaceEx function in Windows for C/C++.

Comment: There's not function in standard Common Lisp for that, but lots of implementations have foreign function interfaces to call C functions, and some have POSIX compatibility layers, too.  What specific implementation are you using?  There may also be libraries out there to provide cross-implementation funtionality like this.

Comment: I'm using **SBCL**. I found that a lot of **Node.js** lib using Command Line tool `df` to get disk space info but not support Windows. It's there a available Common Lisp portable lib for Windows, Linux, Unix and Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a new project [cl-diskspace](https://github.com/muyinliu/cl-diskspace) using statvfs to get disk total/free/available space in Common Lisp. Support Mac/Linux/Windows.

Update: 2015-07-11 now support Windows! Thanks to pjb, Guthur, Fare, |3b|

### Install cl-diskspace with QuickLisp:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/muyinliu/cl-diskspace.git
$ cp -r cl-diskspace ~/quicklisp/local-projects/
```

### Load cl-diskspace with QuickLisp:

```
(ql:quickload 'cl-diskspace)
```

### Usage of cl-diskspace:

#### Get disk space information

```
(diskspace:disk-space "/")
```

Will get something like this:

```
127175917568
16509661184
16247517184
```

Means that the total space is 118.44G, free space is 15.38G and available space is 15.13G

#### Get disk total space

```
(diskspace:disk-total-space "/")
```

Will get something like this:

```
127175917568
```

#### Get disk free space

```
(diskspace:disk-free-space "/")
```

Will get something like this:

```
16509661184
```

#### Get disk available space

```
(diskspace:disk-available-space "/")
```

Will get something like this:

```
16247517184
```

Comment: The detail could be found at [cl-diskspace](https://github.com/muyinliu/cl-diskspace), cl-diskspace use CFFI to wrap system's API to get disk space information.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, it would call an executable to do that using a library.
Calling `df -h` with IOLib for example.
But this is not portable (particularly IOLib, but there are other libraries), and you have to parse the output of the commands.

That's one reason I love programs which have "machine readable" outputs: you can glue them up programmatically (à la shell script).

Another way would be to actually call these c function, using cffi or uffi (ffi standing for foreign function interface), but I haven't used neither, so I can't say much about it.

Oh, search on quickdocs.org, there is probably a library exactly for that, or maybe just to access the OS's API.